# ¿Cómo hacer que cada dato coincida con su etiqueta en matplotlib con python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, matplotlib

Tengo un problema colocando cada etiqueta en el eje x a cada dato, ¿cómo puedo hacer que cada dato (vela) se corresponda con su fecha? mi código es el siguiente:

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc
import matplotlib.dates as md
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
from matplotlib.finance import date2num

# Generar numpy.array con los 4 datos, convirtiendo la fecha en flotante para graficar
convertir = lambda x: date2num(datetime.strptime(x.decode("utf-8"), '%Y%m%d%H%M'))
fecha, apertura, alto, bajo, cierre = np.loadtxt('datos_tratados.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True, converters={0:convertir})

ohlc = []
for i in range(len(fecha)):
    agregar = fecha[i], apertura[i], alto[i], bajo[i], cierre[i]
    ohlc.append(agregar)

# Generar el gráfico ohlc y configuraciones básicas del eje x
figura = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot2grid((1, 1), (0, 0))
candlestick_ohlc(ax, ohlc, width=0.00035)
xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%H:%M')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)

for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
    label.set_rotation(90)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(50))
plt.xlabel('Hora')
plt.ylabel('Precio')
plt.title('EURUSD')
plt.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

Resulta así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intente moviendo el valor de `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator())`

Además me gustaría eliminar las fechas anteriores y ese espacio en blanco anterior a mis datos ¿cómo lo hago?

Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si es exactamente lo que quieres pero si solo deseas que se muestren las etiquetas correspondientes a cada uno de tus datos puedes usar `xticks` y pasarle directamente la columna fecha para que la use como etiquetas. Esto mantendrá el g´rafico igual pero solo mostrará una etiqueta por cada vela. Logicamente esto puede producir solapamiento de etiquetas si dos datos están muy juntos.

Por otro lado puedes modificar los espacios en blanco a ambos lados de la gráfica usando `set_xlim()` y los valores máximos y mínimos de la columna `fecha` más algo de margen:

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc
import matplotlib.dates as md
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
from matplotlib.finance import date2num

# Generar numpy.array con los 4 datos, convirtiendo la fecha en flotante para graficar
convertir = lambda x: date2num(datetime.strptime(x.decode("utf-8"), '%Y.%m.%d %H:%M'))
fecha, apertura, alto, bajo, cierre = np.loadtxt('datos_tratados.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True, converters={0:convertir})

ohlc = []
for i in range(len(fecha)):
    agregar = fecha[i], apertura[i], alto[i], bajo[i], cierre[i]
    ohlc.append(agregar)

# Generar el gráfico ohlc y configuraciones básicas del eje x
figura = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot2grid((1, 1), (0, 0))
candlestick_ohlc(ax, ohlc, width=0.025)
xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%H:%M')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)

plt.xticks(fecha)
ax.set_xlim(min(fecha)-0.05, max(fecha)+0.05)

for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
    label.set_rotation(90)



plt.xlabel('Hora')
plt.ylabel('Precio')
plt.title('EURUSD')
plt.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

Con datos inventados para el csv, con intervalos de tiempo diferentes entre datos para ver la diferencia, obtenemos algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: De nuevo, muchisimas gracias, me has salvado.